# Image upload via Squarespace API

Tags: javascript, node.js, post, multipartform-data, squarespace

I'm trying to upload a product image using the Squarespace developer API. The examples on their website (https://developers.squarespace.com/commerce-apis/upload-product-image) are in cURL. This is what I have written in javascript.

```
const form = new FormData();
    form.append("file", fs.createReadStream("./images/" + data._id + ".png"));
    const send_img = await fetch(
      "https://api.squarespace.com/1.0/commerce/products/" + img_id + "/images",
      {
        method: "POST",
        headers: {
          Authorization: "Bearer " + process.env.SQUARESPACE_API_KEY,
          "User-Agent": "MYUSERAGENT",
          "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data",
        },
        body: form,
      }
    );
```

Unfortunately, when I send this request, no file is sent.

```
{
  type: 'INVALID_REQUEST_ERROR',
  subtype: null,
  message: "Expected exactly one file part named 'file', but found none.",
  details: null,
  contextId: 'AWBREYTOOZEWWRIESHRE'
}
```

What will be the best way to resolve this error?

Answer (score 0):

```
  # The cURL flag below automatically sets `name` to "file"
  # and `filename` to the specified filename.
  # If not using cURL, it’s strongly recommended to use a library that supports
  # `multipart/form-data` requests so the parameters below can be specified:
  #     `name` = "file"
  #     `filename` = "YOUR_FILENAME"
  # If `name` is not set to "file" and/or `filename` is not specified then the request fails
```

I think that, as noted in the `cURL` command you need to set a filename.

```
// Set filename by providing a string for options
form.append("file", fs.createReadStream("./images/" + data._id + ".png"), 'myfilename.png');
```

See [form-data documentation](https://github.com/form-data/form-data#void-append-string-field-mixed-value--mixed-options-) for more details on the `.append` method

Comment: I added what you suggested. I even tried passing an object with {name:"file",filename:"myfile.png"}. Unfortunately I got the same error.

Comment: you can try to change your Squarespace URL to a https://httpbin.org/post , and log the response. The server basically just mirrors back your requests, then you can post it here.

Comment: I ran it. https://pastebin.com/9T2aCa4J.